# How do I name stuff in my character string?

Tags: r, character

I am new to R so I am a bit confused with the basics. Currently, I have a character string that I created using the following code:

```
coldf <- character (length=2500)
```

I would like to change the content in the characters. For every fifty characters, I wanted to change it to something else. A quick glimpse of some of the things I wanted to change is apple, banana, pear, and orange. In the end, I want my character string to be something like this:

```
“apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” “apple” "banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana” “banana" “pear”... etc
```

Comment: @MichaelChirico Yes! Thank you so much.

Comment: `rep(c("apple", "banana", "pear"), each = 50)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're after the `rep()` function. It has three basic usages:

1. Repeat a vector by concatenating it to itself a number of times
2. Repeat a vector by repeating each element a number of times
3. Repeat a vector by repeating different elements a different number of times

To illustrate:

```
x = letters[1:5]
# 1
rep(x, 4)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
# 2
rep(x, each = 4)
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "d" "d" "e" "e" "e" "e"
# 3
rep(x, 5:1)
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "d" "d" "e"
```